# Javascript loop with ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been struggling all afternoon to understand how to make this work, hopefully someone can help. I have a simple requirement to run through a list of checked check boxes, retrieve some data from the server, fill an element with the data expand it. So far I have the following code;

```
function opentickedrows() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            tid = $(this).attr('name').replace("t_", "");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/transfer_list_details_pull.php?id=' + tid,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#r' + tid).html(data);
                    $("#r" + tid).show();
                    $("#box" + tid).addClass("row-details-open");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the ajax calls all seem to happen so fast that 'tid' isn't being updated in the ajax call. From what I have read I believe I need to wrap this up into a couple of functions with a callback but I just can not get my head around how. I'd be really grateful if someone can set me on the right path.

Comment: This is a scope issue with `tid`; (you have it as a global) and not a "timing" or other issue; i.e. put it inside the scope of the callback function `success`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, so when the success callback is invoked, `tid` has the value of the last item of the `$('input[type=checkbox]')`.

You could use a closure:

```
function opentickedrows() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            tid = $(this).attr('name').replace("t_", "");
            (function(tid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/transfer_list_details_pull.php?id=' + tid,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#r' + tid).html(data);
                        $("#r" + tid).show();
                        $("#box" + tid).addClass("row-details-open");
                    }
                });
            })(tid)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: even add `var tid = ...` to keep out of that global scope BUT that does make the assumption it is NOT needed outside this scope however.