# Javascript loop with ajax call generates the same JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call ajax in a loop, while my URL is also changed in each iteration.
problem: I get the same last respond, from both 2 iterations.

I tried to use closure, as suggested in [Javascript loop with ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191608/javascript-loop-with-ajax-call)
but the responds are still the same.

maybe the problem comes because I use `request.responseText` instead of `jsonData`

so -

- How can I use `jsonData` ?

  or
- How can I get different `request.responseText` in each iteration ?

sample code:

```
  function getLimitedSysInfo() {
      var $myObjects = $('.some-class');
      $myObjects.each(function() { 
          var objId = $(this).attr('id');
          var eId = objId.substring("my_obj".length);    
          
          (function(eId) { // use closure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191608/javascript-loop-with-ajax-call

              var strURLGet = "http://www.test.com/my_test/get_info.php?p1=p1val&e=" + eId;
              console.log(eId + " -> " + strURLGet); // => prints out as expected
                
              request = $.ajax({
                  type: "get",
                  url: strURLGet,
                
                  cache: false,
                  complete: function(jsonData) { 
                      console.log("fSys() complete");  // => prints out as expected         
                  },
                  success: function(jsonData) { 

                      console.log("fSys() success");   // => prints out as expected
                
                      console.log("fSys() success " + eId + " -> ***" + request.responseText + "***" );  // => Here is the problem:
                          // => eId prints out as expected  
                          // => but request.responseText is the same for both calls


                      var myJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText); // => so I always get the same JSON    
                      
                
                  } // success
              }); // request

          })(eId) // use closure.

        });  // each
  }
```

Comment: Why your server gives you the same response for different `eid` values isn't something we can know. Just check your `network` tab in Chrome developer tools to make double sure that you're making different requests

Comment: The network tab can be used to verify not just that the requests are different, but that the responses are different. If it shows that you do, in fact, have different requests but the same response, you either have a problem on the server or are making incorrect assumptions about how the server should respond

Comment: it feels like your `request` variable is global, therefore being override by your second call. So when it reach the success callback, it is not the same as what it was when it started.

Comment: @Nicolas Is correct, you need to declare `var request` in the function to keep them from overriding each other.

Comment: The code you presented seems okay, so maybe the problem could be on the server? You could try make the same requests manually using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or a similar tool, in order to check if the results are the same.

Comment: Why are you using `request.responseText` in the first place? Isn't `jsonData` the response you want?

Comment: Also, as an aisde to the issues, sending AJAX requests in a loop is a bad idea. Change the logic so that you aggregate all data in to a single request.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, You could also build an array of promises and resolve it using `Promise.all`

Comment: @Barmar, I use request.responseText because I did not manage to parse jsonData into a JSON object, and I did not find many examples to parse it :(

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonData)` should do it.

Comment: You can also use `dataType: 'json'` and jQuery will parse it automatically and put the result in `jsonData`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I am not sure I can. actually my get_info.php is translating each ajax call to more complicated ajax call in a different site

Comment: in FireFox console, I can see the GET responses are different.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I did not know the result is already JSON object. so I tried to parse it, and it gave me errors...

Comment: It will also parse it automatically if the server sends `Content-type: application/json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code, and use

```
 request = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: strURLGet,
        dataType: 'json',    // <- new addition

        cache: false,
        complete: function(arrData) { 
            console.log("fSys() complete");             
        },
        success: function(jsonData) {  // Note: Since jQuery 1.8, .success, .error and .complete are deprecated in favor of .done, .fail and .always.
            console.log("fSys() success");

            // jsonData is already JSON object. no need to parse it
            // simply use 
            var status = jsonData.status;
            var user = jsonData.user;
              ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Promise.all](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-all) to get all the data then manipulate them, please see this sample code

First a function to get the ids from DOM nodes

```
const getIds = () => {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.some-class');
  const ids = [...nodes].map(node => node.id.substring('my_obj'.length));

  return ids;
}
```

Then a function to get the urls given the ids

```
const urls = ids => ids.map(id => `http://www.test.com/my_test/get_info.php?p1=p1val&e=${id}`);
```

Then the function to get the data

```
const fetchData = async urls => {
  const responses = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));
  const json = await Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()));

  return json;
}
```

Finally how to consume the data obtained from calling the previous function

```
fetchData(urls).then(json => console.log(json));
```

I have not tried this code just write based on what is shown in your example,